# Searching for a specifc item in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects and I need to find the last element that matches a specific condition. I tried to do it with `each_reverse`, but it ended up with too much of a code:

```
matching_item = nil

items.reverse_each do |item|
  if (item.type_id == 10)
    matching_item = item
    break
  end
end
```

Is it possible to make it shorter?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
matching_item = items.reverse.find{ |i| i.type_id == 10 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [`Array#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select) and return the last match:

```
matching_item = items.select {|i| i.type_id == 10}.last
```

Leave off the `.last` if you decide you want all matches:

```
matching_items = items.select {|i| i.type_id == 10}
```

Comment: There are nice, though they search all the array and don't stop when the find the fitst matching element. Any way to to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
items.reverse_each.detect{|item| iterm.type_id == 10}
#or
items[items.rindex{|item| item.type_id == 10}]
```